# A group such that all its subgroups are finitely generated

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finitely-generated, infinite-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

I have been thinking about the following question:

Let $G$ be an infinite group with the property that every proper subgroup of $G$ is finitely generated. Can we say that $G$ is always finitely generated?

Of course, I do not expect a positive answer to this, but I cannot think about any examples regarding this claim. Any counterexample would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a quick observation that may or may not help: If such a group exists it cannot have any finite-index subgroups (because the finitely many generators of the subgroup together with representatives of the cosets would generate the whole group)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the group
$$C(p^\infty)=\cup_{n\in N} C(p^n).$$
Each subgroup of this group is a finite group, but it is not finitely generated.

This group has many different names: the Prüfer p-group or the p-quasicyclic.

Comment: If one does not know this group, it's not so obvious how that union is performed. Please, add a reference in this answer, for example saying this is called the Prufer group.

Comment: @AlexWertheim That's not true, ${\mathbb Q}/{\mathbb Z}$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of the Prüfer $p$-groups $C(p^\infty)$ for all primes $p$, none of which are finitely generated.

Comment: @DerekHolt: whoops, yeah, every *finitely generated* subgroup is cyclic. Deleted my previous comment...

Comment: These $C(p^\infty)$ for $p$ prime are the only abelian examples. I actually don't know whether there are any non-abelian examples.

Comment: @Crostul if helpful, view it as the group of those complex $z$ such that there exists $n$ such that $z^{p^n}=1$.